# Google Translate: what's the document size limit?

Tags: limit, google-translate

I'm trying to send a PDF file of only 2.75 Mb but with 156 pages to Google Translalte.
It gives the error "The page you requested was too large to translate".
I have tried to split the PDF into 2 parts but Google Translate always gives the same error.
Could someone tell me the maximum size I can send (pages, Mb, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can translate 5000 character at a time using the Google Translate apps per ["Request too big" in Google Translate](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/translate/bmu8XS_8iTs)